# ¿Se sigue utilizando "mesero" en su acepción inicial?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, palabras-raras

Desde el [Diccionario de autoridades](http://web.frl.es/DA.html) y hasta la actualidad viene recogida en los diccionarios la palabra **mesero** como:

> El que después de haber salido de aprendiz de algún oficio, se ajusta con el Maestro a trabajar, dándole de comer, y pagándole por meses.

No es hasta 1984 cuando aparece una segunda entrada:

> De mesa.
>
> Camarero o camarera de café.

que ha ido evolucionando hasta el actual [mesero<sup>2</sup>](https://dle.rae.es/mesero?)

> De mesa.
>
> 1. m. y f. *Am. Cen., Bol., Chile, Col., Ec., Méx. y R. Dom.* Camarero de café o restaurante.

En mi experiencia, este segundo uso (mesero = camarero) es el más extendido hoy día, o que me lleva a plantear ¿se sigue utilizando la primera forma?

Comment: Yo, desde luego, no he escuchado ese uso nunca.

Answer (score 1):

Aunque la RAE aún lo incluye, lo cierto es que es un término ya en desuso, al menos aquí en España, si acaso a nivel literario puede utilizarse para describir determinados contextos populares de otro tiempo, en general solo se utiliza en su acepción de  *"Camarero de café o restaurante"*.

Incluso en otros diccionarios, como el Espasa, se encuentra esta de camarero como la única acepción que podemos leer, desapareciendo aquella *... del que sale de aprendiz y se ajusta con el Maestro a trabajar, dándole de comer, y pagándole por meses*.

Esta concepción como "modo de enseñanza o vivencia" es ya obsoleto, pues apenas quedan oficios de ese tipo, personas internas que cuidan de mayores,  recolección de frutos y alguno más, en cualquier caso no continua con un oficio ó tradición que sirva para mantener una manera de vivir. Y menos común un maestro, en cualquier especialidad, que ofrezca una comida y una paga por meses, eso ha desaparecido por completo.

Así en la actualidad, estos conceptos "*alguien que ha salido de aprendiz de algún oficio y que se ajusta con el Maestro a trabajar*", se ha sustituido por los "contratos de practicas", que normalmente duran unos meses ó un año, y la mayoría de las veces sin remuneración.